# Carrierwave - Presence validation triggering if filetype not on whitelist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In my rails 4 app I am using carrierwave to upload images.

```
class UserItemImage < ActiveRecord::Base

  include PicturesHelper

  attr_accessor :foo

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  belongs_to :user_item
  validate :picture_size
  validates :picture, presence: true

end
```

I am using this whitelist in my `picture_uploader.rb`

```
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end
```

My form

```
  <%= simple_form_for :user_item_image, url: user_item_user_item_images_path(@user_item), multipart: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :picture, as: :file, label: false, input_html: {multiple: true, class: 'image-file'} %>
```

When I try attaching a file with an extension not on the whitelist.  I am getting a "can't be blank" error message.  If I remove the presence validation, then the white_list validation error displays correctly.  I really want the file extension error message to show up instead, because technically it's not blank it just has an incorrect file.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I’m having the same problem!

Comment: @gnclmorais I think I just ended up using this to handle file input http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem and ended up doing this:

1) Make sure to put `mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader` before validations.

2)

```
validates :attachment, presence: true, unless: :attachment_errors_exist?

def attachment_errors_exist?
  errors[:attachment].present?
end
```

I figured if other errors exist (most likely it's `extension_white_list_error`), then the attachment must be present already, right? I guess you can further examine the message itself to determine whether it is `extension_white_list_error`, but this is good enough for me.