# Can't Use Validates Presence On Picture Rails 5.x

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :tag1, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :tag2, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :tag3, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :picture, presence: true
  validate  :picture_size
  validates :ispublic, inclusion: { in: [ true, false ] } 

  private

    # Validates the size of an uploaded picture.
   def picture_size
     if picture.size > 5.megabytes
       errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB in size.")
     end
   end
end
```

microposts_controller.rb snippet:

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
  if @micropost.save!
    flash[:success] = "Post created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    @feed_items = []
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end

def micropost_params
    params.require(:micropost).permit(:tag1, :tag2, :tag3, :picture, :ispublic)
end
```

Test that is failing snippet:

```
tag1 = "This"
tag2 = "Is"
tag3 = "Sparta"
image = File.open("test/fixtures/p_avatar.png")
assert_difference 'Micropost.count', 1 do
  post microposts_path, params: {micropost: { tag1: tag1, tag2: tag2, tag3: tag3, picture: "image", 
  ispublic: false }}
end
```

Test error:

```
Validation failed. Picture can't be blank.
```

I am using CarrierWave...[based on other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373601/carrierwave-presence-validation-triggering-if-filetype-not-on-whitelist) I was wondering if I can't use the `presence: true` validation with a picture, but I thought the `@micropost.save` would just store whatever as a string (varchar).  For testing purposes, I just want to make sure a valid string is passed, but maybe that isn't even necessary if CarrierWave and picture_size validation is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. In the Rails spec, there is a function called [`fixture_file_upload()`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/TestProcess/FixtureFile/fixture_file_upload) which does all the heavy lifting of creating the image object for me (some sort of upload to a cache it seems) and making the Model.save() method validate it and store the string in the db.

Thanks to this site it informed me a bit on image upload testing without going through FactoryBot: https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/carrierwave-rails-test-fixtures/

Ultimately I decided I micropost doesn't *require* a picture (A la Twitter).